# Firebase phone auth failing on app already in production with status code 17028

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

We are using firebase phone authentication to authenticate our users. We've been using it for over a year now.

Today at 13:00 GMT, new users are receiving **17028 An invalid safety_net_token was passed** after entering their phone number.

I tried to verify each of the causes I found on the firebase docs:

1. Verifying the SHA1 and SHA256 on the firebase console (We use the fingerprints that are on the play store console)
2. Verifying the package name

The last app update was on October 1st and since then thousands of users created an account with Firebase Auth and there were no configuration changes on the firebase console.

Upon looking at other StackOverflow questions, the error we are getting is not the same as **17028 A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that this application's packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the Firebase Console** Even though it is the same error code, in our case, it says an **invalid** token was passed.

We are using firebase with react-native-firebase module.

EDIT: After disabling Android device verification API from Google Cloud Console the verification is now working but with no device verification. (Users have to verify they're not robots with a CAPTCHA).

Comment: Are you still encountering the issue? Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: Yes we are still having the issue. Check my edit

Comment: Facing same problem today, disabling Device check helps solving the problem

Comment: This is a problem for 100% of apps that uses firebase authentication?

Comment: @DouglasIanitsky I still don't know. Even the GCP support still did not reply to our case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: It is working fine now, and the outage has been fixed.

[image]

It looks to be a firebase internal issue, and the only solution now is to disable "Android Device Verification" and all your users will see the Recaptcha page.

check
https://status.firebase.google.com/
https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/TYeQBVB4kkzyk2kE8vbP

### [image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've been checking the status page before they updated it.